# Opencart Journal 2 Admin dashboard and main content

Tags: opencart

Need some ideas what could be wrong with journal 2 theme in OC 2.3.x version.
Saved all FTP content and sql database like a backup copy, when I tried to restore it - happens like in screenshot you can see.

Getting error in main page and can't see any content of shop.
When I'm going into main shop page, getting error like this:
**Fatal error: Class 'Journal2Page' not found in /home/.../public_html/system/journal2/startup.php on line 257**
The line in that file is:

```
 256. require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'journal2/classes/journal2_page.php');
 257. $journal2->page = new Journal2Page($this->registry, $journal2->html_classes);
```

It looks like everything should be okay but not loading it at all.
Also, the admin dashboard looks like lost footer and header, also I can't open journal theme control in that menu.
Any ideas what could be wrong? And solutions?
[admin dashboard image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGTTT.png)

Comment: Have you tried contacting the theme developer's support channel?

Comment: I am sure you have already **refresh modifications** & **deleted** `/vqmod/checked.cache`,`/vqmod/mods.cache` & `/vqmod/vqcache` files. Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check if `/public_html/system/journal2/classes/journal2_page.php` file exists.
If not, something went wrong when you restored the files and you should re-upload all of them just to be sure.